# How to use FacebookSDK v4.6 with Xcode 7 beta

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.x

I can use the FacebookSDK with Xcode 6, but with Xcode 7 and FacebookSDK for IOS 9 I can't seem to make it work.
I always get the following errors:

```
error: 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found
error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/astanciu/Documents/IOS projects/facebooktest/facebooktest/Bridge-Header.h'
```

I tried solutions found on other threads, but still can't make it to work.
What it works is to configure everything in Xcode 6 and than open the project with Xcode 7 and convert it.
But I want to add fb integration to an existing project.

Any ideas how to make fb sdk to work in Xcode 7 ?

Comment: Did you install it by CocoaPods?

Comment: No, without CocoaPods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by actually copying the Facebook desired frameworks (in my case CoreKit, LoginKit and ShareKit) from the ~/Documents/FacebookSDK folder to the project folder.

To achieve that, I just dragged the frameworks into the project folder on XCode, but I CHECKED the option "Copy items if needed".

After that, everything worked in the first build.

I'm using Facebook SDK 4.7 and XCode 7.1.